# Ord Instance of STRef

Tags: haskell

Is there a good reason that `STRef` is not, or could not be made, an instance of either `Ord` or `Hashable` typeclasses?.

I have seen arguments against including `Ord IORef` in the past, and I recall the stated reason was space constraints. This reason is what lead me to consider `Hashable`.

My motivation is use of `STRef`s in sets, which could either be done directly through `Ord`, or indirectly, using the ordering of its hash.

Edit: I'm hoping to perform observable sharing within the `ST` monad. `STRef`s allow for this, but when an imperative algorithm calls for comparison between a set of references, implementing this as a search through a list is slow (*O(n)*).

I'd ideally like to use a set or hashmap. The ordering in this case makes no difference ultimately to the stability of the algorithm, so that actual references are irrelevant to the final outcome of the algorithm.

Comment: What Hash are you using? You can't use the underlying value as that would make `Ord` no longer constant, which I would think any container implementation would assume.

Comment: You might be interested in [`StableName`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html#t:StableName)s.

Comment: @Guvente: the hash would be supposedly done on the "address" same way `Eq` is implemented.